# Spring-Integration: Using a recipient-list-router from inside of a chain to achieve iteration but getting a routing error

Tags: xml, spring, spring-integration, declarative

From a spring-integration chain `A` I'm calling a chain `B` that may "loop" on itself until all information recovery is satisfied (since the first call may retrieve information that itself needs to be resolved by subsequent calls).

chain `A` calls to chain `B` via a gateway call, hence expects a return message:

```xml
<int:chain input-channel="A_channel" />
    ...
    <int:gateway request-channel="B_channel" />
    ...
</int:chain>
```

*In case that it's useful, I'll note that the chain A is itself called from a gateway call originating from an HTTP inbound-gateway.*

Chain B then embeds a recipient-list-router:

```xml
<int:channel            id="B_channel" />
<int:chain   input-channel="B_channel" >
    <int:gateway request-channel="C_channel" />
    <int:transform ... set the payload to indicate if still more work to do ... />
    <int:recipient-list-router resolution-required="false">
        <int:recipient channel="B_channel" select-expression="payload.size() != 0" />
    </int:recipient-list-router>
</int:chain>
```

The is giving me an error.  Either of

- "No channel resolved by router" (when no `resolution-required` attribute is set)
- "No channel resolved by router and no defaultOuputChannel defined" (with `resolution-required` set to `false`)

I'm wanting an iterative loop based upon a condition and I was thinking that recipient-list-router would give me that possibility, but I'm not finding the magic invocation.  Also, if the recipient-list-router at the end of a chain resolves no output channel, I was thinking that it would continue to the output-channel that the chain itself would have configured, in this case, the replyChannel set up by the gateway call to chain B.

What will allow this kind of iterative execution from within a declarative environment?

Comment: It is not clear what you mean by "iterative loop" in this context, the RLR is simply a mechanism to route the message to 0 or more channels. The only iteration there is iterating over the recipients and. deciding whether or not to send the message there.

Comment: If the payload is a list of elements, you can use a splitter to break it apart if that is what you mean.

Comment: The "iterative loop" part is in the example code itself: within the chain ```B```, which has as its ```input-channel``` the ```B_channel```, the RLR has a ```recipient``` that chooses the ```B_channel```.  You could say that it's "recursive" but I'm calling it "iterative" as it "loops" on the ```B_channel``` until the RLR ```selector-expression``` is no longer true.

Comment: This is not for splitting but for making a series of calls to an external service until all of the unresolved items are resolved.  With each new return, we may discover a new set of "transitive" unresolved items, hence cannot use a simple splitter on a fixed initial set of items.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Solution using `<int:filter ...>` as proposed by @artem-bilan:

```xml
<int:channel            id="B_channel" />
<int:chain   input-channel="B_channel" >
    <int:gateway request-channel="C_channel" />
    <int:transform ... set the payload to indicate if still more work to do ... />
    <int:filter expression="payload.size() eq 0" discard-channel="B_channel" />  
    <... post-iteration operations here ...>
</int:chain>
```

Much more compact and easier to read.  Thanks!